# youtube caption size default value not updating in the player settings even after onapichange

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Youtube caption font size default value not changing from the onapichange. actually the change is happening but inside the player its not selecting the given value inside the settings dropdown.

I tried the below code, its changing the caption size on screen and its not refreshing the value on page reload.

Thank you in advance.

```
<!-- <iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SqcY0GlETPk?cc_load_policy=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
<!-- <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rB9ql0L0cUQ?cc_load_policy=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
<!-- <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rB9ql0L0cUQ?cc_lang_pref=fr&cc_load_policy=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          
          
          playerVars: {
            cc_load_policy : 1
          },
          events: {
            onReady: onPlayerReady,
            onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange,
            onApiChange: onPlayerApiChange
          },
        });
      }
      
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.setVolume(20);
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {       
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }       
      }
      
      function onPlayerApiChange(event) {      
        
        player.setOption('captions', 'fontSize', 2);   
       
      }
      
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```